# Directly expose my Kafka brokers to external consumers or use a http-based gateway?

Tags: apache-kafka

Which one is the best way to expose my Kafka ecosystem to thirdy-party applications that need to consume or publish messages?

1. Use a gateway (http-based) to hide the complexity of implementing a Kafka client + protecting my topics + having it language independent, as every language (afaik) have libs to easily deal with HTTP requests.
2. Directly exposing my Kafka brokers using Kerberos in order to guarantee security.

As for the first option, AWS have a nice solution using its API Gateway + Kafka Client and Kafka Rest Proxy, but I'm not sure that's the first is the best option.